# MS Access Project In TFS Build

Tags: ms-access, tfsbuild

I have a question for all of you and please any ideas are welcome. We have alot of MSAccess database projects in our repository on which developers work and do there tests in Dev Envoirment on there own. As you all know compiling a databse project is itself a wrong statement, cause you actually need to test your scritps and reports and everything else againt a databse. SO what can we do in TFS build script in case of MSAccess Projects , i am out of ideas. Anybody who has come across this issue and have done something about it, i would really appriciate if you share.

Any example or link which will explain how to go about it would be even more better. Please understand that its an MS Access Projects.

Thanks
BOB

Answer (score 0):

Compiling is not entirely an wrong statement.

In the VBA side, there is a an option under the Debug menu called Compile (I don't believe its truly a compile like in C, but it is pre-parsing your code, etc.). This combined with building an MDE in the GUI side equates to compiling.

Typically, when working with the VBA I'll run the Compile frequently to make sure everything is syntactically correct, etc.

As far as testing goes, once you know that it compiles you still aren't done. If can compile and still be wrong. That's why you need automated test scripts. I'd consider a little script/form within the MDB that you can run manually to open and close all the Reports are concerned about and exercise the code. Actual form functionality would be more tricky to automate, but could be done as well.

Comment: Yes, it's a compile, but to p-code, not machine code. See http://trigeminal.com/usenet/usenet004.asp?1033 for some explanation of how that works in Access.